# Google docs spell checker API - is it available?

Tags: api, google-docs, spell-checking

Is Google Docs spell checker available?
I have tried MS Azure - but it's not as good as I need.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Answer:

*No, there is no API which gives visibility to Google Docs spell checker.*

#### More Information:

In the past, there was an unofficial, undocumented API that was hosted by Google for spell checking, available at *`http://www.google.com/tbproxy/spell?lang=en`*.

**This has now gone** and there was never a replacement released. You can see remnants of its history by doing a [Google search for this URL](https://www.google.com/search?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2Ftbproxy%2Fspell%3Flang%3Den).

As per Stack Overflow guidelines I can not recommend you a spelling checker API for reasons of bias, though you can find plenty paid and free APIs by searching the web yourself.